# How to remove commits from parent branch when rebasing?

Tags: git, rebase

Suppose I have a branch `widget`, which was made by branching off `feature` and adding several commits about building the `widget`.

I now want the widget to be available in `master`, without the rest of the feature. Is there an automatic way to make a new version of `widget` that just consists of `master` plus the stuff about the widget?

Simply doing checking out `widget` and doing `git rebase master` doesn't work because that would bring all the other parts of the feature with it.

I can do `git rebase --interactive master` but that requires manually identifying and deleting the non-widget related commits. Is there are command that I can give the three branch names to and have it do this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

One quite straightforward way would be to cherry-pick commits to a new branch created from master :

```
git checkout -b widget-2 master
git cherry-pick feature..widget

# then to apply that to the real widget branch and get rid of the temp

git checkout -B widget widget-2
git branch -d widget-2
```

---

But we could have skipped the temporary branch altogether, now that I think of it :

```
git checkout --detach master
git cherry-pick feature..widget
git checkout -B widget HEAD
```

Comment: Looks perfect, I didn't remember that you can give cherry-pick a commit range like that.

Comment: final steps to make it equivilent to do the git rebase would be `git checkout widget; git reset --hard widget-2; git branch -d widget-2`.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
0-0-0-0-0-0 <--master
     |-0-0-0-0-0-0 <--feature
                 |-0-0-0-0-0 <--widget
```

and you want to turn it into this:

```
0-0-0-0-0-0 <--master
     |    |-0-0-0-0-0 <--widget
     |-0-0-0-0-0-0 <--feature
```

The git rebase command is quite flexible.  You can use `git rebase` with the `--onto` option to do this:

```
git rebase --onto master feature widget
```